# Magento - Cannot add products to a manual order within backend of the Admin Panel

Tags: magento, product, manual

I'm experiencing an issue where when I go to create an order within the Admin Panel of Magento (1.4.1.1) I can start the order, select the customer, then select the language, it loads all information fine, but when I go to "Add Products I can open that up and select the products, but when I click "Add Selected Product(s) to Order" it shows the loading screen briefly (Please Wait) then it loads nothing.

I can add the items from the wishlist over, or the last ordered items, but not new products from the "Add Products".

I've read numerous threads about this in regards to Magento 1.5 but i'm on Magento 1.4.1.1. 
Here is a link to a thread where it's briefly discussed. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/230381/

I've tried the changes to XML regarding the ext.js but I don't think Magento 1.4.1.1 has that .js file. I believe it was implemented in 1.5 so that doesn't help.

Here's the kicker... My friends computer which runs Firefox 11 worked fine last night when adding an item. I upgraded my browser to Firefox 11 but it still doesn't work for me here at the office. Nor does any other browser. I've tried to disable my plug-ins and extensions but that doesn't fix it. I've also cleared all Cache possible (website, server, browsers, etc.)

Can someone please help so I can create an order while a customer is on the phone and not run into this problem? I'm lost on what the common denominator is here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to answer the question I asked in case anyone runs into this...

I recently changed the prototype.js to the newest version so my Lightbox script would work in IE9 along with the image slider on product pages. The new Prototype.js fixed those issues, but that's what caused the issues in the backend. The backend uses the prototype.js framework for when adding images to a product and also adding items to a manual order in the backend. 
I was having both of those issues.

What I did was restore the old prototype.js file which cured the issues of not being able to see images in the back end along with not being able to upload them to a product page, along with not being able to add products to a manual order that is created in the admin panel.

Once I fixed those issues, I was back to square one with the Lightbox script not working for IE9 along with the image slider on product pages. I simply put a short bit of code in the .htaccess file to have the website emulate IE8 if any IE browser was detected.

The code i used...

```
BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support
```

I hope this helps anyone out there with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue... We resolved this by uploading the new prototype.js into js/prototype/ and naming it:

prototype-new.js

We then updated the page.xml for the frontend theme changing the following line to use the new Prototype file, as follows:-

page.xml

```
FROM: <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>

TO:   <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype-new.js</script></action>
```

In doing this the backend continues to use the older / bundled prototype.js and the front end uses: prototype-new.js

Laurie